# Sticky headers with paging library in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-library

I'm currently playing around with the new Jetpack compose UI toolkit and I like it a lot. One thing I could not figure out is how to use `stickyHeaders` in a `LazyColumn` which is populated by the paging library. The non-paging example from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#sticky-headers) is:

```
val grouped = contacts.groupBy { it.firstName[0] }

fun ContactsList(grouped: Map<Char, List<Contact>>) {
    LazyColumn {
        grouped.forEach { (initial, contactsForInitial) ->
            stickyHeader {
                CharacterHeader(initial)
            }

            items(contactsForInitial) { contact ->
                ContactListItem(contact)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm using the paging library I cannot use the `groupedBy` so I tried to use the `insertSeparators` function on `PagingData` and insert/create the headers myself like this (please ignore the legacy `Date` code, it's just for testing):

```
// On my flow
.insertSeparators { before, after ->
        when {
            before == null -> ListItem.HeaderItem(after?.workout?.time ?: 0)
            after == null -> ListItem.HeaderItem(before.workout.time)
            (Date(before.workout.time).day != Date(after.workout.time).day) ->
                ListItem.HeaderItem(before.workout.time)
            // Return null to avoid adding a separator between two items.
            else -> null
        }
    }

// In my composeable
LazyColumn {
    items(workoutItems) {
        when(it) {
            is ListItem.HeaderItem -> this@LazyColumn.stickyHeader { Header(it) }
            is ListItem.SongItem -> WorkoutItem(it)
        }
    }
}
```

But this produces a list of all my items and the header items are appended at the end. Any ideas what is the right way to use the `stickyHeader` function when using the paging library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it to work by looking into the source code of the `items` function: You must not call `stickyHeader` within the `items` function. No need to modify the PagingData flow at all. Just use peek to get the next item without triggering a reload and then layout it:

```
LazyColumn {
    val itemCount = workoutItems.itemCount
    var lastWorkout: Workout? = null

    for(index in 0 until itemCount) {
        val workout = workoutItems.peek(index)

        if(lastWorkout?.time != workout?.time) stickyHeader { Header(workout) }
        item { WorkoutItem(workoutItems.getAsState(index).value) } // triggers reload

        lastWorkout = workout 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The data shows correctly, but when I scroll new items into view (or scroll back up), then the content of some items become invisible. I think this has to do with compose not detecting that it's on screen so it just skips rendering. Is this something you've experienced as well?

Comment: I did not, make sure to call `workoutItems.getAsState(index).value` as this is triggering reloads from the paging library. Do not use the item you got with `peek` for the layouting.

Comment: why should we use peek while rendering sticky headers however we use get function from lazypagingItems for rendering item?

Comment: Be careful using this solution: the for loop will iterate every single time the user will fetch new items and, if you have a lot of results (e.g. hundreds of thousands or millions), it will easily run out of memory or at least degrade the scroll performance (think about iterating over a million items on the UI thread every time you fetch a new page).

Comment: @RobertoLeinardi Paging should only give you the current visible pages. With a appropriate page size this should not be any problem!

Comment: @Cilenco Unfortunately what you says is not what I'm experiencing: try to put a logcat before the `val workout` and print the `index`: what I'm seeing is that the `LazyPagingItems` triggers a recomposition of the `LazyColumn` every time it changes (e.g. a new page is fetched), running the for loop again. If you have a long list this means running this for loop multiple times over the entire list. Btw my code is slightly different: `for (index in 0 until lazyPagingItems.itemCount)`. From where is the `indices` in your for loop coming? I can't find it in `LazyPagingItems`.

Comment: `getAsState` is now deprecated. See: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/paging

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue in your code was that you were calling `this@LazyColumn` from inside an `LazyItemScope`.

I experimented too with `insertSeparators` and reached this working LazyColumn code:

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
    for (index in 0 until photos.itemCount) {
        when (val peekData = photos.peek(index)) {
            is String? -> stickyHeader {
                Text(
                    text = (photos.getAsState(index).value as? String).orEmpty(),
                )
            }
            is Photo? -> item(key = { peekData?.id }) {
                val photo = photos.getAsState(index).value as? Photo
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same for this solution: the for loop will iterate every single time the user will fetch new items and, if you have a lot of results (e.g. hundreds of thousands or millions), it will easily run out of memory or at least degrade the scroll performance (think about iterating over a million items on the UI thread every time you fetch a new page).

Answer (score 2):

Up to date solution for this is:

```kotlin
val lazyPagingItems = customersListPagingItems
for(index in 0 until lazyPagingItems.itemCount) {
    // important: use .peek() to get the item without causing page load
    when (val peekingItem = lazyPagingItems.peek(index)) {
        is Header -> stickerHeader(key=index or peekingItem.stableId) {
            // important: use .get() in composable to get the actual item and cause next page load
            val header = lazyPagingItems[index] as Header
            HeaderUi(header)
        }
        is Item -> item(key=index or peekingItem.stableId) {
            // important: use .get() in composable to get the actual item and cause next page load
            val item = lazyPagingItems[index] as Item
            ItemUi(item)
        }
    }
}
```